# Cypress - how to handle async commands

Tags: javascript, authentication, cypress

I am just trying to handle impossible stuff in Cypress :)
Basically I am taking token from indexedDB using 'idb' library -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb
To get that I have created async function

```
export const getTokenFromIndexedDB = async () => {
    const db = await openDB('StorageDB')
    const keys = await db.getAllKeys('LocalStorage')
    const key = keys.filter((key) => key.startsWith('authUser'))
    const value = await db.get('LocalStorage', key[0])
    return value.value.token
}
```

In the test I would like to make couple of API calls using the token. I am using that using `then()`, but ending up with a big chains of commands. Is there any way to assign a value of the called function (to await for the value) in Cypress?
Other option is to call `getTokenFromIndexedDB()` before each call, but this is not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of @Afzal tried to show, save the token into an environment variable within your function.

```js
export const getTokenFromIndexedDB = async () => {
  const db = await openDB('StorageDB')
  const keys = await db.getAllKeys('LocalStorage')
  const key = keys.filter((key) => key.startsWith('authUser'))
  const value = await db.get('LocalStorage', key[0])
  Cypress.env('token', value.value.token)
}
```

You can call the function in a `beforeEach()` to avoid using `.then()`.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  getTokenFromIndexedDB()
})

it('uses the token', () => {

  cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://example.com/api',
    headers: {
      Authorization: Cypress.env('token') 
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

the "cy.wrap()" command can be used to store the value returned from async function and then use it in test.

```
it('should make API calls using token from indexedDB', () => {
    // Get token from indexedDB
    cy.wrap(getTokenFromIndexedDB()).as('token')
    // Use token in API call
    cy.request({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://example.com/api',
      headers: {
        Authorization: Cypress.env('@token') // Use token from indexedDB
      }
    })
})
```

This allows to use the token from indexedDB in all API calls without having to redefine it for each one.

Comment: That would seem to be incorrect. The function returns a Promise, despite being `async` inside it's no async outside (the return value is `Promise<token>`). Did you try it out? I know that Cypress sometimes resolves promises - does the alias do that?

Comment: Also `Cypress.env('@token')` is the wrong usage